# 'Pick up' vs 'Picking up'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, usage, verb-forms

I was reading a story "The piece of string" by Guy de Maupassant, when I read this line:

> "Mr. Manana, the harness man saw you **pick up** the pocketbook."

I read it several times and it didn't seemed correct to me.

I want to ask if **picking up** would be the *correct form* to use instead of **pick up**, or *better*. Or is it just a difference of American English and UK English ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference I can see is the matter of completion.

> I saw him pick up the book

Indicates that the action was completed.

> I saw him picking up the book

Does not necessarily mean that the viewer ever saw the action completed.

The difference is pretty much negligible and comes down to a stylistic choice. Both options are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The phrases "I saw you pick up the book"

and "I saw you picking up the book"

They both mean essentially the same and they are both correct.

Comment: Welcome to the ELL :-). A more in-depth explanation would make this a better [answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/answering) this way it's more of a comment.